# NameError: name 'HTMLSession' is not defined when calling yahoo_fin.options.get_expiration_dates()

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I'm calling `yahoo_fin.options.get_expiration_dates()` from a very simple code, such that it's unlikely that I have loaded other modules with the same name.

My whole code is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

from numpy import *
from yahoo_fin import options

plt.style.use("seaborn")

expirationDates = options.get_expiration_dates("goog")
```

The output of the last line is:

```
NameError: name 'HTMLSession' is not defined
```

Can you help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yahoo_fin requires requests-html for a few of its functions, including the `yahoo_fin.options.get_expiration_dates` method.  You can install it using pip (it requires Python 3.6+):

```
pip install requests-html
```

Once installed, you need to restart your Python session.  [This link](http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/) provides information on what functionality requires requests-html.